# Deploy a single war to multiple tomcats using tomcat-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, war, maven-tomcat-plugin

I'm trying to deploy a single war project to multiple tomcats using `mvn tomcat:deploy`. Since these are listener project (aka workers), their overlapping names are irrelevant.
When I have

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <url>`http://192.168.116.54:8080/`manager/text</url>
        <server>standaardTomcat</server>
        <path>/picalcworker</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

a single war will be deployed on that server. Though I cannot have multiple 'plugins' of the same groupId artifactId combination, so simply copy this and change the url will result in a warning and only one (the latest) to be deployed. 
This plugin further seems to allow:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>1</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://192.168.116.52:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>standaardTomcat</server>
                <path>/picalcworker</path>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
        <id>2</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://192.168.116.53:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>standaardTomcat</server>
                <path>/picalcworker</path>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

but then `mvn tomcat:deploy` will try to deploy to `localhost`, since `<configuration><url>` was empty in this plugin's root (but I cannot supply a singular url there, since I need multiple). Also possible tomcat7 and tomcat6.
I really like the deploy and undeploy options. Does anybody know how to make this work, or some reasonable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

currently not possible.
Note the plugin is now hosted at Apache see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html .
Can you load a jira for that ? That need a bit of code (maybe you can add a patch :-) )

Comment: +1 for suggesting a new version of the plugin and the link. And, indeed, it appears this plugin is not created for the purpose I was looking for. The execution part is merely for specifying different execution goals, not for the misuse of deploying to multiple tomcats. Though the org.apache.tomcat.maven version seems to ignore the <url> tag, so tries to deploy it on `localhost`.

Comment: either I see it incorrectly, but it seems the newer version only deploys to a local tomcat. I was browsing a bit, and saw another guy with a similar (the localhost issue) in the summer of last year. (which you responded to) It seems like a powerful plugin, are my requirements that odd?